# Inserting code into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have a input where users enter their code, PayPal code to be more specific. And I always get this error when submitting the code to the database.

```
"Not Acceptable!
An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security."
```

So I tried updating the code via PHPmyAdmin like this:

```
UPDATE store
SET paypal = "codehere"
```

And that didn't work, but when I entered '' instead of "" it works.

So my question is, how can I adjust the insert code so it will work. Here below is the current code:

```
// Here I store the input value
$paypal = $_GET['paypal'];

if (!empty($paypal)) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE store 
        SET paypal = :paypal";
$stmt1 = $connection->prepare($sql2);                                  
$stmt1->bindParam(':paypal', $paypal, PDO::PARAM_STR);          
$stmt1->execute(); 
}
```

Thanks in advance! And let me know if I didn't provide enough information.

Comment: This is a firewall configuration issue (mod_security). Your paypal code probably resembles a social security number or credit card number. Take a look at https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/ModSecurity-Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQ). Specifically, *"Extrusion Detection Model - ModSecurity can also monitor outbound data and identify and block information disclosure issues such as leaking detailed error messages or Social Security Numbers or Credit Card Numbers."*

Comment: plus, the way you're querying, it will update your entire db. use a `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Any way around it without disabling mod_security?

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling mod_security in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using `htmlentities($paypal)` for the query, and then reversed it by using `html_entity_decode($paypal)`.